# Is there any "clean" way to track the progress/intermediate results of a file upload in a WorkManager?

Tags: android, file-upload, android-workmanager

I'm trying to refactor my app to use WorkManager and RxWorker to upload files to the server. I need to track intermediate results of upload and notify observers with current upload progress.

So far what I've read is that the Worker can only return a single result or an error when the task is completed.

There is no way of returning intermediate results, which in my case are needed for tracking an upload percentage.

For example, RxWorker returns a `Single` as a result of `createWork` function, which means that only a single result can be delivered to observers.

Did anyone found a solution to implement this without using additional static Rx `Subject` in the worker?

Answer (score 0):

From WorkManager version `2.3.0-alpha01` it is possible to track Worker progress.

More information you can find at [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/intermediate-progress).